# Vimium: something like "f" for input fields?

Tags: vimium

In `Vimium`, is there something like `f` for input fields? E.g. in a form with 10 input fields, I directly want to jump to the 5th, instead of only `gi` and tabbing through. Is that possible using `Vimium`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as in many shortcuts in `vim` you can prefix a command with a number. I.e. to jump to the 5th field you type `5gi`.

Other vim style examples (It isn't related to vimium. I included it only to illustrate the approach):

- `3dd` delete 3 lines
- `2j` go up 2 lines
- `5p` paste the buffer 5 times